# What to use as DB Host when installing WordPress?

Tags: mysql, iis-7.5, wordpress, localhost

I am aware of how daft this question seems.

I am installing WordPress on two load balanced servers (hardware load balancer), with MySQL set up in Master-Master configuration with an installation on each server. The WordPress installation will be hosted on a UNC share.

Now, when it comes to setting up WP, we need to specify the Database Host, the default for which is localhost. However, since WP is on the UNC Share, is localhost going to refer to the server executing the request, or the IP of the storage in which it is hosted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

localhost will be the server on which the server is executing and will generally be a local loop back address such as 127.0.0.1 and set up in the /etc/hosts file.